# Using Variables in Basic Authentication in an API Katalon-Studio

Tags: variables, authentication, using, katalon-studio

I have been trying to use variables for the Username and Password in the katalon-studio API, basic authentication using the following syntax:

Syntax:

[image: ${Syntax}]

GlobalVariable syntax:

[image: GlobalVariable.Syntax]

However none of them are working.
please advise.

Comment: This is the Katalon Docs Says for basic : https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/authorization-basic.html#basic

Comment: Hello, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might came a little bit too late, but maybe someone will find this in the future...

What the authorization tab does (and what basic authorizaton means - as mentioned in [it's documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/basic-authentication/) ) is encoding the string of `"${username}:${password}"` by Base64.

What I did was mimic the "Update to header" button of the Authorization tab by first encoding the said string:

`String basicAuthToken = "${username}:${password}".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()`

Assuming `authToken` is a variable of the request with the type of `String`
Then just skip the Authorization tab and put this value straight into the header:
Name: `Authorization` Value: `Basic ${authToken}`

And now just pass the `basicAuthToken` as a parameter to the Webservice Request the same way you would any other variable:

`WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('id_of_your_WSR_object', [('authToken'):basicAuthToken, ...any other variables]))`